# Compare a 3d model to 2d image

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

Is there any way in openCv to compare a 3d model I have created to an object in a picture. Say I have a 3d model of a cow for example and I want to find the cow in the picture is there any way to search the image using the 3D model.? This would allow for a cow to be recognized at any angle? Would be possible for a algorithm in opencv to use a 3d model to learn for the data sets?

Comment: you can project 3D model points to your 2D image with cv::projectPoints